# AjaxUploadControl does not fire onuploadcomplete method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to implement the AjaxUploadControl functionality on my site but it does not fire the OnUploadComplete method. Instead, it simply says file uploaded 100%, but the file is not in the specified folders. I have set breakpoints in the OnUploadComplete method and have been able to determine that this method is never being reached. It almost seems to be jumping into an infinite loop as the Cancel button displays, but none of the buttons on the screen are clickable once an attempt has been made to upload a file.

The .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AjaxTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="AjaxTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
            <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="ajaxUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The codebehind file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class AjaxTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender,   AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = "~/SiteImages/" + e.FileName;
        ajaxUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));
    }
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't set the right enctype and method UploadedComplete will never fire.

Comment: try adding enctype="multipart/form-data" into your form tag.

Comment: I added what you suggested into my form tab, so that it now looks like this "<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">", but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: no, if you use ajax control toolkit, you do not have to do this.

Comment: Do you have some logic in `Page_Load` that depends on `IsPostBack` property? Do you have parameters in query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem that I am having. I was trying to implement the functionality in a website versus a web app. I created a test web app platform and it worked flawlessly. I am a beginner to AJAX and did not realize that this would cause issues, however, does anyone know a solution to get this functionality to work in a website. I'm afraid that there is too much to easily port over to web app at this time.

Answer (score 1):

The property is `OnClientUploadComplete`, not `OnUploadComplete`.

Refer to [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx).

> Events
>
> UploadedComplete - Raised on the server when a file is uploaded
>   successfully. In this event an instance of AjaxFileUploadEventArgs is
>   passed in the argument that contains file name, size and content type.

Comment: I am not wanting to perform client side java script. I am attempting to do it server side in the codebehind.

Comment: if it is the case, then see my edit. the event you use is wrong.

Comment: Intellisense does not contain an entry for UploadedComplete?

Comment: please check http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx and click the event & property .

Comment: I have seen that, I have tried plugging it into my code. This site http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/05/01/ajax-control-toolkit-may-2012-release.aspx and several others reference it in the way that I am. I will try UploadedComplete again and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you don't set the right enctype and method UploadedComplete will never fire.</strike>
<strike>try adding **enctype="multipart/form-data"** into your form tag.</strike>
[image]
**e.g.**

<strike>`<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`</strike>

**Code behind:**

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = "~/SiteImages/";
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName)));
}
```

**Code inline:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
            onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />   
    </div>
    </form>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I also added the method="post" and still no luck.

Comment: which version of Ajax control toolkit you are using?

Comment: try this OnClientUploadComplete="ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete"

Comment: I need to do this server side, and also when I change that it makes all of the buttons disappear.

Comment: I recommend download Latest version of Ajax Control Tool kit and add into your project, because i have just tested with newer version it does fire the event and breakpoint gets hit.

Comment: Version of Toolkit i am using is 4.1.60919

Comment: That is the version that I am using as well.

Comment: I have updated the code please check. it has successfully uploaded the file into the specified folder.

Comment: I wonder if the fact that my code recognizes the control as ajaxToolkit:FileUpload instead of asp:FileUpload has anything to do with it possibly? I tried your code with the exception of that and still did not get into the event method. @MMK

Comment: my page code has <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

Comment: I added the assembly reference, but it is still doing what it was previously. I have no clue what could be going on.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem you were having is that you needed a HTTP handler in your web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

I had the very same issue (red error on upload, event in .cs file not firing at all ), now resolved by adding that to my web.config

Answer (score 0):

KINDLY FOLLOW THE FOLLOWING RULES (.NET 4.0)   OR (.NET 4.5 FRAMEWORKS)
MAKE SURE FOLLOWING STEPS WERE USED IN YOUR PROJECT

1. HTML PAGE (MUST BE LIKE THIS)

   ```
   <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <div>
       <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
       <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" ClientIDMode="Static" ContextKeys="dd" MaximumNumberOfFiles="4" />
   </div>
   </form>
   ```
2. IMPORTENT WEB.Config SHOULD BE (HAVING FOLLOWING TAGS **for .net 4.5**)

   `<system.webServer>
       <handlers>
        <add name="aa" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
       </handlers>
     </system.webServer>`
3. IMPORTENT WEB.Config SHOULD BE (HAVING FOLLOWING TAGS for **less than 4 or 4.5**)

`<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</httpHandlers>`