# AjaxFileUpload server events not firing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an asp.net web site application where I want to perform multiply file upload using AjaxControlToolkit file upload component, but `OnUploadStart` and `OnUploadComplete` methods does not fire when I upload files. And also only the first file is uploaded and then it stops.

[image]

My code:

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="FileUploader" runat="server" Mode="Auto" OnUploadComplete="FileUploader_UploadComplete" OnUploadStart="FileUploader_UploadStart" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,gif,png" />

Protected Sub FileUploader_UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxFileUploadEventArgs)
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/Data/Gallery/Pictures/" + GetFolderName() + "/") + e.FileName
    FileUploader.SaveAs(path)
End Sub

Protected Sub FileUploader_UploadStart(sender As Object, e As AjaxFileUploadStartEventArgs)
    'Create folder
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("~/Data/Gallery/Pictures/" + GetFolderName())
End Sub
```

I set breakpoints to the events, but they are not firing. I added `enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"` (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457639/ajaxuploadcontrol-does-not-fire-onuploadcomplete-method) topic) to the  tag and also HTTP handler to web.config file, but it still does not work properly. What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For a **web site** (important distinction between a *web application* as it seems to work fine), it looks like when using the `OnUploadComplete` and `OnUploadStart` attributes on the control, it does not work.

Instead, try handling the event directly in the vb code-behind.
Also, don't forget about using Server.MapPath for your path when creating the directory.

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="FileUploader" runat="server" Mode="Auto" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,gif,png" />

Protected Sub FileUploader_UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxFileUploadEventArgs) Handles FileUploader.UploadComplete
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/Data/Gallery/Pictures/" + GetFolderName() + "/") + e.FileName
    FileUploader.SaveAs(path)
End Sub

Protected Sub FileUploader_UploadStart(sender As Object, e As AjaxFileUploadStartEventArgs) Handles FileUploader.UploadStart
    'Create folder
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Data/Gallery/Pictures/" + GetFolderName()))
End Sub
```

Hopefully this works for you.